# How can I create a font in Java from a .png file?

Tags: java, graphics, fonts

So I have an image that I can work with to create a font out of for my game, and I wanted to know how I could manipulate the code to create a font (preferred .TTF font) out of it?

Comment: A [true type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) font will typically be a [font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font) that is vector based, rather than bit mapped.  So converting it to TTF will be extremely difficult as some of the information that colored the individual pixels is now lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I know is that ttf, otf, pfm fonts are more like vector infos, and not pixel graphics.

- Find a similar free and existing font in the [goolefontdirectory](https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/)
- or make you own font with [Fontographer](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontographer/) (could take some time)